# What is the relationship between the MVC Display decorator and View applied using EditorFor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working through an example of creating an Editor Template in MVC4.

I added the following to my Model:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email"]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Added this to the View for the model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
```

And created an EditorTemplate named EmailAddress.cshtml with just this line:

```
 @Html.TextBox("", null, new {@class="text-box single-line", type="email", placeholder="Enter an email address"})
```

I couldn't get the placeholder to show in Chrome until I changed the Display attribute to this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
```

Can someone please describe to me why it didn't work before I changed it? What is the relationship between that attribute and what is generated when I call EditorFor, and how did this change cause the placeholder show up correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: from what I can see in what you posted you are missing a closing parenthesis on your first display name.  From my experience you can name the field whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

in model, the decorator

```
 [Display(Name = "Some Name")]
 public string myproperty{get;set;}
```

is used to display labels in view, which are accessed with

```
@Html.Labelfor(m=>m.myproperty)
```

I believe that it got nothing to do with placeholder